# What is the counterpart of "cross-env" in python?

Tags: python, node.js

In Node.js, we use "cross-env" to set env variables. It can run on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --watch src --experimental-modules ./src/app.mjs",
},
```

Is there a counterpart in python?

Comment: This question should be reopened, it's perfectly valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python ecosystem it's more common to rely on a custom config.py file which handles to get things from system variables or set reasonable defaults. [This article](https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-manage-the-configuration-in-python-4623049e841b) can detail more on this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `os.environ`? Read and write value works the same way as with dictionary type. Since it is an environment variable, value can only be string type though.

Update:
If you only want to set environment variable when running `dev` mode, you can use the python `sys` library to check if the run command has `dev` argument. If so then you can set the environment variable `NODE_ENV` to `devlopment` by using the assignment expression `os.environ['NODE_ENV'] = 'development'`. `os.environ` should work on all operating systems you memntioned. After that you can run the command `nodemon --watch src --experimental-modules ./src/app.mjs` on Python using `check_call` function from Python's`subprocess` module. Remember to set `check_call` `env` argument to `os.environ` in order to load the environment variables you set into `env`.

Here is an example file`script.py`:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and ('dev' in sys.argv):
    os.environ['NODE_ENV'] = 'development'
    subprocess.check_call('nodemon --watch src --experimental-modules ./src/app.mjs', shell=True, env=os.environ)
```

So when you want to run `dev` mode, you can enter the command:

```
python script.py dev
```

Comment: Sir, I'm asking how to solve it in python.

Comment: It is a built-in feature of `os` library. You can check out the documentation here https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ

Comment: My purpose is not to read the env variable. What I ask is how to set the env variables into script on multiple OS platforms. For the code I pasted in the question, we can run "npm run dev" to set "NODE_ENV" to "development" before starting "./src/app.mjs" on Windows, Linux and Mac OS. If there were a counterpart for python, it would be wonderful.

Comment: `os.environ` can set environment variable into script on multiple OS platforms using the assignment expression. For example, in your case it will be `os.environ['NODE_ENV']='development'`. I thought your environment variable is `dev` and its value is `cross-env NODE_ENV ... ./src/app.mjs` since you didn't specify the variable name and value. You can check if the program is running in `dev` mode by using `sys` module in Python. You can use `check_call` function from `subprocess` module to run `nodemon`. I've updated my answer so you can try it out. Let me know if you encounter any issues.

Comment: I'm using pipenv(similar to NPM for node) to control the project of python. And the custom script is my favorite part, see https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#custom-script-shortcuts. So, can I write a command like this: 'test = "cross-env HOST=localhost pytest"'?